# The column is overflowed in table

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

Here is my problem. My columns are overflowed and I can't see it. 
I know that some columns have a lot of data. 
How can I edit HTML or CSS for that? This web I'm writing by Laravel framework.

[image: Column is overflowed]

Here is my source code, please view it. I'm using bootstrap for this.

```
<div class="box" ng-controller="TinTucNewController">
            <div class="box-header">
               {{csrf_field()}}
              <h3 class="box-title">Danh Sách Tin Tức</h3> <br>
                    <button class="btn btn-new btn-xs btn-create">
                    <a href="{{route('them')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>"  Bấm vào đây để thêm dữ liệu"</a></button>

            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
              <table  id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead><tr>
                  <th>Mã Tin Tức</th>
                  <th>Thể Loại</th>
                  <th>Tiêu Đề</th>
                  <th>Tóm Tắt</th>
                  <th>Nội Dung</th>
                  <th>Hình Ảnh</th>
                  <th>Nổi Bật</th>
                  <th>Lượt Xem</th>
                  <th>Tạo mới</th>
                  <th>Cập nhật</th>
                  <th>Trạng thái</th>
                  <th>Công Cụ</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
                 @foreach($ds_tt as $tt)
                <tbody><tr>
                  <td>{{$tt->tt_ma}}</td>
                  <td>{{$tt->tt_theLoai}}</td>
                  <td>{{$tt->tt_tieuDe}}</td>
                  <td>{{$tt->tt_tomTat}}</td>
                  <td>{{$tt->tt_noiDung}}</td>
                  <td>
                  <img width="80" height="50" src="{{asset('upload/tintucnew/'.$tt->tt_hinh)}}"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    @if($tt->tt_noiBat == 0){{'Tin Thường'}}
                    @else
                    {{'Tin Hot'}}
                    @endif
                  </td>
                  <td>{{$tt->tt_luotXem}}</td>
                  <td>{{$tt->tt_taoMoi}}</td>
                  <td>{{$tt->tt_capNhat}}</td>
                  <td><?php echo ($tt->tt_trangThai==2)?'Khóa':'Khả dụng' ?></td>
                  <td>


                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-edit">
                    <a href="{{ route('tintucnew.edit',['Tintucnew' => $tt->tt_ma])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></button>

                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete"
                    ng-click="confirmDelete({{$tt->tt_ma}})">{{ method_field("DELETE")}}
                       {{csrf_field()}}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>


                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
                @endforeach
              </table>
            </div>

          </div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap for you styling?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help if we cannot see the code? Who knows, maybe you it's all one giant `<img>` tag with a picture of an overflown table. Please add a repro.

Comment: yes, I do. I used boostrap

Comment: sorry, i edited @LazarLjubenović . i think it's not <img>. because i have height and width in this tag

Comment: i want my columns is resized smaller, some column with many words will be replaced by "...".
How can you use any tags for this ? I need your helps.

Comment: One option might be https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#responsive-tables